# Swift : Hide UIView from Bottom on Scroll like Twitter

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, uiview, tableview

I want to `hide UIView while scrolling down and showup when scrolling up`.
So I have a `tableView` and I would `like to hide the UIView above` it as the user `scrolls down and showup when scroll up` (here is example below):

[image]

`UIView` below `navigation controller+Embedded Segmented Controller` in the UIView.

Should I use: `scrollViewDidScroll` ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes, you can try do it in the scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: Please show the code you've used to try to implement this, and describe what's not working about it. Or if you haven't tried, please go and try first.